# Instantaneous alternative to a local variable with getter?

Tags: c++, performance, getter

Consider this scenario:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() : _var{5} {}
    inline int getVar() {
        return _var;
    }
private:
    int _var;
}

void func(Test& t) {
    int var = t.getVar();
    int a = 1 + var;
    int b = 2 + var;
    ...
    int z = 26 + var;
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
         func(t);
    }
}
```

While profiling a similar execution during ~40s, I saw that the getVar() call alone costs me around 0.8s, which seems huge for just accessing an int.

However, by setting my _var as public and accessing it directly (t._var) instead of using a local variable and Test's getter, it is even slower.

Is there a magic c++ solution that is nearly instantaneous to access "_var"?

Comment: Simple magic is to ask your compiler to optimize.

Comment: How did you measure? What compiler optimization level was used then?

Comment: Caching the value in a local variable is as fast as it will get, as that lets the compiler store the value in a register instead of fetching it from memory every time.

Comment: Since you are not actually using a-z, an optimiser could remove the code entirely, giving you the impression that the calls to getVar() are dominating execution time.

Comment: I would suggest using something like [this](http://rextester.com/CBZP12393) if you want to test this.  It's compiled with `-O0`, but you can use `-O1`, `-O2`, or `-O3` to see the results with different levels of optimisation.  This test used `volatile` qualifiers to prevent optimisation; similar results are obtained without `volatile`.

Answer (score -1):

Methods defined within a class definition are always *inline*. Note that *inline* doesn't necessarily mean that calls to that method are replaced with the method's body, have a [look](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

It's most likely your time measurement is faulty, or you didn't turn optimizations on and the compiler didn't may optimize the hell out of it.

Comment: It is not true they are always in lined.  Inline is a hint. Compiler is free to ignore it

Comment: _inline_ does mean that the definition of a function "may appear more than once within a program". It lost it's original intention of _inlining_ a function's body.